# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm currently trying to use React + Typescript + Redux and I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to test the Redux Store setup via chrome devTools. I know I butchered the code (very new to Typescript) and I'm getting this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')' every time I test it. I tried declaring a global window state, installed redux-dev-tools, but still very lost.

This is what my store/index.tsx file look like:

```
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
  StoreEnhancer,
} from "redux";
import { devToolsEnhancer } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

let enhancer;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  enhancer = applyMiddleware(thunk);
} else {
  const logger = require("redux-logger").default;
  const composeEnhancers =
    (window && (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose;
  enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
}

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, devToolsEnhancer({}));
};

export default configureStore;
```

and my types/index.d.ts:

```
import { StoreEnhancer } from 'redux'

export {};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    store: {};
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__?: () => StoreEnhancer;
  }
}
```

And finally my src/index.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import configureStore from "./store";

const store = configureStore();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  window.store = store;
};

function Root() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Root />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I will also attach screenshots of my file setup:
[image: My file set up]

And my console error:
[image: My Console error]

I am open to all suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is that the store setup code is using outdated patterns and a lot of handwritten code.  Today, you *should* be using our official Redux Toolkit package to write your Redux apps, and as part of that, RTK's `configureStore` API.  It does all that same work with just a few lines:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer
  }
})
```

That automatically combines reducers, adds the Redux DevTools extension setup, and adds the thunk middleware.

See our docs for guidance on setup:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start
- https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure

As for the specific error message you're seeing... the code *seems* like it would run.  My guess is that something is wrong with the `process.env.NODE_ENV` check you added and so it's not assigning `window.store`.

RTK also works much better with TypeScript than legacy Redux code does.